# convert inch to metric value

Tags: excel, vba

I try to create a function which convert an inch value to a metric value.

In the cell there is e.g. "1/12 inch".

My function till now looks like following:

```
Public Function ConInToMe(inp As String) As Integer

    If InStr("inp, inch", ",") = 4 Then

        inp = Left(inp, Len(inp) - 4)
        inp = CInt(inp)
        ConInToMe = WorksheetFunction.MRound(inp / 25.4, 1 / 16)
        ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "# ??/??"
    Else
        MsgBox ("no inch value detected")
    End If

End Function
```

I delete the substring "inch" to convert the value. I always get #VALUE in the cell. What I am doing wrong? Any idea?

Greets and thx in advance,
yab86

Comment: have you tried it without the numberformat?

Comment: Yes, I did. Nothing change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works if you would try it with `0.5 inch` instead of `1/2 inch`. I guess that the `/` messes up the conversion to double.

```
Public Function ConInToMe(inp As String) As Double

    Dim holder As Double

    If InStr(inp, "inch") > 0 Then
        inp = Left(inp, Len(inp) - 5)
        holder = inp
        ConInToMe = WorksheetFunction.MRound(holder * 25.4, 1 / 16)
        'Debug.Print ConInToMe
        'ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "# ??/??"
    Else
        MsgBox ("no inch value detected")
    End If

End Function
```

EDIT:

Its ugly, but it works for the `/`:

```
Public Function ConInToMe(inp As String) As Double

    Dim holder As Double

    Dim con1 As Double, con2 As Double

    If InStr(inp, "inch") > 0 Then

        If InStr(inp, "/") > 0 Then

        con1 = CDbl(Left(inp, InStr(inp, "/") - 1))
        con2 = CDbl(Mid(inp, InStr(inp, "/") + 1, InStr(inp, " ") - InStr(inp, "/")))

        holder = con1 / con2
        ConInToMe = WorksheetFunction.MRound(holder * 25.4, 1 / 16)

        Else

        inp = Left(inp, Len(inp) - 5)
        holder = inp
        ConInToMe = WorksheetFunction.MRound(holder * 25.4, 1 / 16)

        End If
    Else
        MsgBox ("no inch value detected")
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: That helps me Marco - thanks. The problem is, that I can not change the original value (e.g. "1/12 inch")

Comment: @yab86 Ok try the edited version. Should work. i know its not pretty, but it works.

Comment: Thank you Marco. I do not understand why I always get the msgbox "no inch value....."

Comment: With what example are you trying to use it? If the value in the cell you are trying it on, does not contain the string "inch" it will always go into the `Else`-case and the `MsgBox` will show. Try it on `3/4 inch` for example.

Comment: Ohh yeah. My mistake - sorry. Thank you so much Marco.

Comment: Does this succeed to change the number format of the cell in the `else` case? Doesn't work for me for instance...

Comment: No i guess not. I forgot to take it out. ThisCell doesn't work neither.

Comment: This was the trick I was trying to solve, to no avail. The OP did not specify the exact problem. I think this is still to solve (strange)

Comment: humm. There is a tricky way to achieve it, I think. Will post it as a complement.

Comment: @yab86 and Marco, take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33921752/copy-pastspecial-cell-format-in-vba-inside-function-dont-work/33927475#33927475) for a technique to copy/paste a format when a custom user-defined function is invoked. :)

Comment: Perfect. Thanks A.S.H. Very nice

Answer (score 0):

The fault is at `inp = CInt(inp)`

`inp` is declared as string, hence cannot assign integer to it.

perhaps a new variable for the working should work

Answer (score -1):

```
package test3;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class inchtometer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("This Is Inch TO Meter Converter");

        float a;
        double b;
        Scanner mtr=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Inch Valuse You Can Covert Meter");

        a=mtr.nextFloat();
        mtr.close();
        b=25.4;
        double c=a*b;
        System.out.println("Meter Values Is ="+c);

    }

}

    enter code here
```