# VBA Variable as Range don't accept worksheet!range as value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a function in VBA

```
Function VLOOKUPnew(ValueToLook As Range, Interval As Range, ColIndex As Integer) As Variant
```

It accepts $A$1:$D$500 but don't accept Name_of_worksheet!$A$1:$D$500

How can i resolve that?

**EDIT**: It's related with this question [copy/pastspecial cell format in VBA inside function, don't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33921752/copy-pastspecial-cell-format-in-vba-inside-function-dont-work/33927475#33927475)

Comment: Works fine for me - what are the **exact** arguments you are passing, and what do you mean by "don't accept"?

Comment: if i try =VLOOKUPnew(I7;$F$2:$G$36;2) it work, because i'm looking in tehe same sheet.   I if try =VLOOKUPnew(I4;LASA!$A$1:$B$5356;2) it gives me #Value!. I suposed this is because the addiction of sheet name. It's the only difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the code inside the function that's the problem. You need to change this:

```
fMatch = Application.Match(ValueToLook, Range(Interval.Address()).Columns(1), 0)

' Obtem o endereço da célula que contem o valor do VLOOKUP
' **********************************************
CellOrigin = Interval.Cells(fMatch, Interval.Columns.Count).Address()
```

into this:

```
fMatch = Application.Match(ValueToLook, Interval.Worksheet.Range(Interval.Address()).Columns(1), 0)

' Obtem o endereço da célula que contem o valor do VLOOKUP
' **********************************************
CellOrigin = "'" & Interval.Worksheet.Name & "'" & Interval.Cells(fMatch, Interval.Columns.Count).Address()
```

otherwise it will search the wrong sheet, and also copy the format from the wrong cells.

Comment: Then please post the exact code you are using. There's nothing wrong with the declaration line itself.

Comment: Sorry, probably my problem was lack of sleep. Thanks. It works! :)